# Choose custom post type template by category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, templates

I need to style my portfolio posts with different templates. My thought is that it would be done by category. I have tried using `in_category` and `is_category` and a lot of other work around's but to no avail. The code in my `single.php` file currently is:

```
<?php if ( '' != locate_template( 'content-'.get_post_type().'.php' ) ) // Check if themplate exists esle get default post content
  {
     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );
  } else {
      get_template_part( 'content', 'post' );
  }
?>
```

And though I seem to understand what its doing can't seem to come up with a conditional allowing it to check the category and returning the template accordingly.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Using single.php with conditional template part inclusion for displaying a specific layout for your custom post type is not the right way to do things.

WordPress has something called the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). The right way would be to create a `single-name-of-your-cpt.php` to display single portofolio items. The same applies to custom post type archives.

The second problem is that categories are a build-in taxonomy. Category archive pages use the `archive.php` template, but you won't see your custom post type show up there, because only posts are included. You could always modify the query via the `pre_get_posts` action, but I don't think that this is what you want.

For your case the best thing might be to use a [Custom Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Let's say that you have a custom post type called `portfolio` and a custom taxonomy called `portfolio-category`.

With this set up you could use an `archive-portfolio.php` template to display all your portfolio posts and an `taxonomy-portfolio-category.php` to display the portfolio posts in a certain portfolio category. You can even create archive templates for certain portfolio categories this way.

For the single views, use `single-portfolio.php` and use [has_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) to check in what portfolio category the post is and include the corresponding template part this way, making sure to have a default layout as fallback.